# How to display a certain HTML if a condition is never met (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Say I had an ngFor loop surrounding an ngIf statement

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition1">
    //display table1
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Now, say I had a second table (call it table2) that I want to display if table1 is not displayed.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition1 was never met and table1 is not displayed">
  //display table2
<ng-container>
```

What is the best way to do this, and is there a way to do this using Angular's data binding features? Or, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular | Display element conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231336/angular-display-element-conditionally)

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Angular ngIf, Else like this

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="condition1; then table1; else table2">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #table1>
  <div>
    table1
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #table2>
  <div>
    table2
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

You can read more about it on this [post](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-else-then)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *ng-template* and *ngIf-else*

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition1;else table2">
    //display table1
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #table2> //display table2 </ng-template>
```

**or**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition1;then table1 else table2"> </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #table1> //display table1 </ng-template>
<ng-template #table2> //display table2 </ng-template>
```